# Failed to limit memory with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My server has **2GB** mem

I launched **2 containers** in the server with docker-compose

Although I set the memory limiti, but it seems not work

[image]

## docker-compose

```
hub:
  mem_limit: 256m
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"
test:
  mem_limit: 256m
  build: ./
  links:
    - hub
  ports:
    - "5900"
```

Comment: Please include the output of `docker info`. Not all kernels enable cgroup memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but try set mem_limit to 256000000 without using 'm'

Answer (score 0):

This is not documented anywhere in docker-compose, but you can pass any valid system call `setrlimit` option in `ulimits`.

So, you can specify in `docker-compose.yaml`

`ulimits:
  as:
    hard: 130000000
    soft: 100000000`

memory size is in bytes. After going over this limit your process will get memory allocation exceptions, which you may or may not trap.